# Creating QgsVectorLayer from ArcGIS feature Service layer using PyQGIS in QGIS 3.28

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, import, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I'm developing a QGIS plugin in Python that lets you add layers from ESRI Feature Services (EFS) to the canvas. This feature has always worked correctly up to QGIS 3.28 (I've tried QGIS 3.28.4 and 3.28.8). In this version of QGIS, I can't create a valid `QgsVectorLayer`. However, it is still possible to add layers from ESRI Feature Services manually using the graphical interface.

Here's an example of Python code that works in QGIS 3.22 but not in QGIS 3.28:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

wfs_url_base = "crs='EPSG:2154' filter='' url='{service_url}/{layer_id}' table='' sql=''"
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(wfs_url_base, baseName="efs_arcgisserver", providerLib="arcgisfeatureserver")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Running this code in QGIS 3.22 add a valid layer to the canvas. However, running it in QGIS 3.28 add an invalid layer.

I haven't found any documentation about a breaking change in QGIS 3.28 involving the creation of EFS layers.

Is there a new way to add an EFS layer in QGIS 3.28 using Python, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that removing "filter=''", "table=''" and "sql=''" from the `wfs_url_base` variable is enough to correct the problem.

The following code therefore works in QGIS 3.28 and QGIS 3.22:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.core import QgsDataSourceUri, QgsProject, QgsVectorLayer
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService

wfs_url_base = "crs='EPSG:2154' url='{service_url}/{layer_id}'"
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(wfs_url_base, baseName="efs_arcgisserver", providerLib="arcgisfeatureserver")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

However, I'm not aware of any documentation indicating this.